# Cython: Not exposing parts of the implementation

Tags: python, c++, cython

I'm making a cython integration model for some code in C++, and I have the following question:

Can I chose to not expose parts of my implementation that are internal?

For example:

myclass.hpp

```
class MyClass {
  private:
   foo _bar;
  public:
   do_stuff();
};
```

I chose to intentionally leave out `_bar` from the cython module, because it is internal to the implementation

myclass.pyx

```
cdef extern from "myclass.hpp":
    cdef cppclass MyClass:
        cdef public void do_stuff()
```

Comment: Did you face any particular probems doing so?

Comment: I'm still trying to compile the simple example, so I'm not sure. The cython doc is very confusing to me.

Comment: So if you have any problems compiling that mention these explicitely in your question please. Ideally as a [MCVE].

Comment: My question is as explicit as physically possible. Cython doc never explicitly says if it is possible for you to not expose part of the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can omit implementation details.

Your Cython code does two things

1. it includes "myclass.hpp" so that the C++ compiler can access the necessary implementation details.
2. It tells Cython about the specific methods, attributes or subclasses (etc) you want to use (in your case `do_stuff`). The only consequence of not telling Cython about a method/detail is that you can't access it directly from Cython.